# static mp3 song delayed starting with jplayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, mp3, jplayer, icecast

I am trying to build a website that plays mp3. I am using:

1. [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) : For client side audio player.
2. [icecast](http://icecast.org/) : For streaming mp3 audio.
3. Other technologies are ruby on rails, nginx, angularjs etc.

My Problem is:

1. jPlayer fully load the song then it start playing
2. So starting the   song is always delayed based on song file size.

Other findings:

1. Byte rang request is working. But still loading the full song first.

My icecast.xml file is as following:

```
<icecast>
<!-- location and admin are two arbitrary strings that are e.g. visible
     on the server info page of the icecast web interface
     (server_version.xsl). -->
<location>Earth</location>
<admin>admin@playstore.com</admin>

<!-- IMPORTANT!
     Especially for inexperienced users:
     Start out by ONLY changing all passwords and restarting Icecast.
     For detailed setup instructions please refer to the documentation.
     It's also available here: http://icecast.org/docs/
-->

<limits>
    <clients>100</clients>
    <sources>2</sources>
    <queue-size>2048</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
         first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
         time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
         it also significantly increases latency between the source
         client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
         might want to disable this. -->
    <burst-on-connect>0</burst-on-connect>
    <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
         specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
         change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
    <burst-size>512</burst-size>
</limits>

<authentication>
    <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
    <source-password>irfan</source-password>
    <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
    <relay-password>passw0rd</relay-password>

    <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
    <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
    <admin-password>passw0rd</admin-password>
</authentication>

<!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
     specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
     wanted or an extension is required
<shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
-->

<!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
<!--
<directory>
    <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
    <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
</directory>
-->

<!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
     It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
     listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
-->
<hostname>localhost</hostname>

<!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
     <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
     <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount>
</listen-socket>
<!--
<listen-socket>
    <port>8090</port>
</listen-socket>
-->
<!--
<listen-socket>
    <port>8443</port>
    <ssl>1</ssl>
</listen-socket>
-->


<!-- Global header settings 
     Headers defined here will be returned for every HTTP request to Icecast.

     The ACAO header makes Icecast public content/API by default
     This will make streams easier embeddable (some HTML5 functionality needs it).
     Also it allows direct access to e.g. /status-json.xsl from other sites.
     If you don't want this, comment out the following line or read up on CORS. 
-->
<http-headers>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</http-headers>


<!-- Relaying
     You don't need this if you only have one server.
     Please refer to the config for a detailed explanation.
-->
<!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
<!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
<!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
<!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

<!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
     useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
     The default is 0 -->
<!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

<!--
<relay>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server>
    <port>8080</port>
    <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
    <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
    <on-demand>0</on-demand>

    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>
-->


<!-- Mountpoints
     Only define <mount> sections if you want to use advanced options,
     like alternative usernames or passwords
-->

<!-- Default settings for all mounts that don't have a specific <mount type="normal">.
-->
<!-- 
<mount type="default">
    <public>0</public>
    <intro>/server-wide-intro.ogg</intro>
    <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
    <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
    </authentication>
    <http-headers>
            <header name="foo" value="bar" />
    </http-headers>
</mount>
-->

<!-- Normal mounts -->
<!--
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

    <username>othersource</username>
    <password>hackmemore</password>

    <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
    <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
    <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
    <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
    <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
    <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
    <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
    <hidden>1</hidden>
    <public>1</public>
    <authentication type="htpasswd">
            <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
            <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
    </authentication>
    <http-headers>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webplayer.example.org" />
            <header name="baz" value="quux" />
    </http-headers>
    <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
    <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
</mount>
-->

<!--
<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
        <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
        <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
        <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
        <option name="headers"         value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
        <option name="header_prefix"   value="ClientHeader."/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
-->

<fileserve>1</fileserve>

<paths>
    <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
    <basedir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/share/icecast</basedir>

    <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
         be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
    <logdir>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/var/log/icecast</logdir>
    <webroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/share/icecast/web</webroot>
    <adminroot>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
    <!-- <pidfile>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/share/icecast/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

    <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
         May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
         and "bind-address" attributes.
      -->
    <!--
    <alias source="/foo" destination="/bar"/>
    -->
    <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
         this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
         the status page
    -->
    <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
    <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
         Both should be PEM encoded.
    <ssl-certificate>/usr/local/Cellar/icecast/2.4.2/share/icecast/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
    -->
</paths>

<logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
    <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
    <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
    <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
    <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
         the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
         otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
         Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
    -->
    <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
</logging>

<security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>
    <!--
    <changeowner>
        <user>nobody</user>
        <group>nogroup</group>
    </changeowner>
    -->
</security>
```

I need to understand how should I can do something that player will start playing the song after loading the very small amount of song to prevent starting delayed.

Comment: Try setting "preload: auto" option http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-preload

Comment: making the same 30-40 seconds delayed

Comment: Ummmm, do you have a source client running a real stream or just a pile of static files? Icecast is not meant for on demand content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it! I found chrome have the problem and it can't start an mp3 encoded music file while loading. But it can play immediately the other supported encoded music. Well this is not a permanent solution. But in my case, encoding all songs for fallback support gives me the trick. Now all major browsers are playing songs successfully.

Comment: can you give me an example for how to encode songs in jpalyer i had same problem in chrome but its working perfect in firefox

Comment: I used ffmpeg to encode songs into various format and provide them as browser demand.